# update a element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, ajaxform

Hi i have a id of #item_quantity in a span. once a button is clicked with and id of #update_cart. I want the span to refresh its contents. the target data would have already been updated on the click also that works, but cant seem to get the span to update its data.

i am using the following script to try refresh it:
the link i m targeting was the same page i was on. Once a product is added to the cart, and the page is refreshed, then the list updates, so i thought i could right a scripts that just refreshes that div once something is clicked and all will be done. but it does nothing.

**script**

```
$(function() {
  $("#update_cart").click(function(evt) {
     $("#item_quantity").load("http://apecenergy.co.uk/products.php?p=4")
     evt.preventDefault();
  })
});
```

**html**

```
<div class="menu_cart_units "><span class="" id="item_quantity">
<cms:number_format quantity decimal_precision='0'/></span>&times;</div>
<div class="menu_cart_option"><cms:show title /></div>
<div class="menu_cart_subtotal"><span class="" id="item_price"> £<cms:number_format line_total /></span></div>
```

**json**

```
                "id":                <cms:show id/>,
                "quantity":          <cms:show quantity/>,
                "price":             <cms:show price/>,
                "line_total":        <cms:show line_total/>,
                "requires_shipping": <cms:if requires_shipping>true<cms:else/>false</cms:if>,
                "name":              "<cms:show name/>",
                "title":             "<cms:addslashes><cms:show title/></cms:addslashes>",
                "link":              "<cms:show link/>",
                "remove_item_link":  "<cms:pp_remove_item_link/>",
                "line_id":           "<cms:show line_id/>",
```

If i go down the ajax json method, there will be multiple ids which relate to different products, from each id i require quantity, name and line total, to be updated in the div.

Answer (score 1):

> what data your request returns??
>
> `$("#item_quantity").load("http://apecenergy.co.uk/products.php?p=4")`

Assuming the user returns valid JSON i would say a simply "success" with count of items as `[{'result':'success'},{'count','<count>'}]` if items updated in cart successfully else return something like `[{'result':'error'}]!` this should be simple as

making ajax call with jquery:

```
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:'Your url that return JSON encoded success with Count of items or Error message',
data:'item id to update here 4 i guess or post Data'
datatype:"JSON",
success:function(data)
{
var tmp=Jquery.parseJSON(data);
 switch(data.result)
  {
     case 'success':
           $('#item_quantity').text(data.count); //update the span  
           break;
     case 'error':
          alert('something went Wrong');
          break;
     default:
          alert('error');
          break;
  }
},
error:function()
{
   alert('Ajax Request Failed');
}
});
```

Comment: the load will execute the url, opening all included files, to find the correct id to reload?

Comment: downvote? sorry for late reply but i was just ensuring that the user returns valid data..as i missed edited tag...edited my answer hope that helps...

Comment: this looks perfect

Comment: i have included my json values. how would i get it to show all ids and the selected values i want from that list? eg. quantity, name and line total to output?

Comment: the link i m targeting was the same page i was on. Once a product is added to the cart, and the page is refreshed, then the list updates, so i thought i could right a scripts that just refreshes that div once something is clicked and all will be done. but it does nothing.

Comment: Hi, so i see two ways of doing this. 1) get script to refresh the id - some reason not  working. 2) try to use the values in the json and get script to update them using that as source. but confuses me.

Comment: hey hi..sorry for previous edit..but lets take this as:
1)create a page that you wish to have content to list with say and add to cart button 
2)on click of button try calling js script or js code in same file which uses ajax call to update the content on server (add items to cart) calling file in point 3.
3)create page which keeps track of your cart items and return the values as json with respective success or error message.

is that make sense to you now?

Comment: yes so have a php file font end with a button to click, 2 click button which makes the request to update details from the json file that i already have. i think i have all components except the correct scripting to bring them together will make a fiddel.

Answer (score 0):

```
// parse the JSON into a javascript object
var cart_items = JSON.parse(json);
// matches all items in the cart_items list, which have the id == 30
// filter returns an array of matched items
var matching_items = cart_items.filter(
    function (item) {
        if (item.id == 30) {
            return item;
        }
    });
// since it should only match one item, we take the first element of the array
var item = matching_items[0];
// print out the items quantity
console.log(item.quantity);
```

Comment: Possible for it to target all ids listed in the cart/ div, and refresh quantity and line price

Comment: Use a for-loop?